# Get average of values of rows of every month and grouped by user

Tags: mysql

I have these tables:

[image: Used tables]

Fiddle of tables: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/18c65

With this query:

`` SELECT user_id AS user, round(AVG(cost_freight), 0) AS average FROM `freights` GROUP BY user ORDER BY average ASC LIMIT 10 ``

i get average of freights(cost_freight) grouped by user **(the values in bold is the authenticated user)**:

[image: first query]

But now I need to get average of freights(cost_freight) of every month grouped by user, the result should be like this:

[image]

and this is where I have tried several ways but I can't get the desired result.

I would very much appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Use one column(MONTH(date)) into group by. Try this one,

```
SELECT user_id AS user,MONTH(date), round(AVG(cost_freight), 0) AS average FROM `freights` GROUP BY user,MONTH(date) ORDER BY average ASC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: i'ts no work because i need group by user the average of every month, this query not returns monthly users average.

Comment: I think should inter change the group by columns, `SELECT MONTH(date), user_id AS user,round(AVG(cost_freight), 0) AS average FROM `freights` GROUP BY MONTH(date),user ORDER BY average ASC LIMIT 10`

Comment: Add some insert statement with test data.